# .Net Call a outside webapi from within your own web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have built a Web Api project in DotNet Core

What I want to do:
I wish to build a web api project in dot net, consume another api, save that to a database, and then call my own web api to collect the data from the database.

Say I want to consume an existing api for example the star wars api: https://swapi.dev/
Should i declare a HttpClient in my Program.cs and then do the request to the star wars api in a Controller?

Why I want to do it: I'm learning, so this is why I'm doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some would recommend creating an StarWarsApiService that you'd register with dependency injection at startup, and write methods in that class that use an HttpClient instance like you mentioned for each endpoint you plan on calling. Bring that service into your controller and call those methods from your controller endpoints.

Comment: Great plan! I'll try it out.